# Why does the ArrayBuilder base class not provide method interfaces?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

ArrayBuilder has no method definitions:

```
abstract class ArrayBuilder[T] extends ReusableBuilder[T, Array[T]] with Serializable
```

Yet, implementations of it will commonly share methods with same interface, up to the generic type argument `T` (taking `mkArray` as an example):

```
  final class ofFloat extends ArrayBuilder[Float] {

    //...

    private def mkArray(size: Int): Array[Float] = {
      val newelems = new Array[Float](size)
      if (this.size > 0) Array.copy(elems, 0, newelems, 0, this.size)
      newelems
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Methods creating new arrays couldn't be abstracted "up to the generic type argument `T`" before `ClassTag`s were introduced; afterwards they could, but it would lose performance (probably very slightly in most circumstances, but this code is called quite often...).
2. Type erasure interacts weirdly with arrays. Any `Array[T]` you have in `ArrayBuilder[T]` will end up being `Array[AnyRef]`. So if you just have abstract methods there, classes like `ofFloat` will end up with a lot of hidden casts which JIT may or may not optimize.